# Google Maps Android API v2 check if InfoWindow is open

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way to check if the info window is open for any Marker on Google Maps v2 Android ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Marker.isInfoWindowShown()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#isInfoWindowShown()) method

Comment: So I have to iterate through all markers every time to check if the info window is open ?

Comment: As only one Info Window can be open at a time, you can consider using `GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowCloseListener` to know when an Info Window has been closed

Comment: That makes more sense!